# pmin() with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a fairly simple question.  For some reason the pmin() function does not work when piped with a dataframe.  See below:

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
pmin(mtcars$am, mtcars$gear)
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
mtcars %>% pmin(am, gear)
Error in pmin(., am, gear): object 'am' not found
Traceback:

1. mtcars %>% select(am, gear) %>% pmin(am, gear)
2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
8. function_list[[k]](value)
9. pmin(., am, gear)
```

What I am missing?  Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: From documentation: "takes one or more **vectors** as arguments"

Comment: Try this: `mtcars %>% mutate(pmin = pmin(am,gear))`

Comment: or use `with()` as a pipe line helper, `mtcars %>% with(pmin(am, gear))`

Comment: @rf7 if my post answers your question could you please mark it the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where your going wrong is that the pipe operator passes the data frame as the first argument. So your trying to run `pmin(select(mtcars,am, gear), am, gear)`.

As Nate's comment suggests, `mtcars%>%with(pmin(am, gear))` does what you want.

Also, a slight modification on Marco's comment. `mtcars%>%transmute(pmin(am,gear))%>%pull`

Comment: thanks @Moody_Mudskipper. Removed them from my answer. That's what happens when you multitask.